# Cache entire response to distributed cache (Redis)

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, redis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to cache an entire page to a distributed cache (specifically Redis) in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC web app. When a user visits a page, the code in the action method and the view cshtml is executed, and a page is generated and sent to the user. I would like this page to get cached at the end of the request, so that when subsequent users visit the page it should get presented from the cache, without having to execute any code in the action method or the view. And more specifically, I would like it to be cached in Redis. I am familiar with how to store key-value pairs in Redis from a web app, and also familiar with how to cache parts of a page to Redis, but I cannot figure out how to cache the **entire** page to Redis.

I have successfully used a Redis specific implementation of the `IDistributedCache` interface to store key value pairs to Redis. This was achieved by installing the Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis.Core NuGet package, and adding the following statement to `ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "localhost";
    options.InstanceName = "SampleInstance";
});
```

Once that was done, I was able to dependency inject the Redis `IDistributedCache` implementation into a controller, and then use statements like `_cache.GetStringAsync()` and `_cache.SetStringAsync()` to store and retrieve key value pairs to Redis. I can also use the `<distributed-cache>` tag helper in a .cshtml page to cache parts of a view.

**However these techniques do not help me to cache the *entire* page, only parts of it.** The code in the action and the view still need to execute, and the page needs to be re rendered, albeit faster since some of it is cached. What I would like to do is cache the *entire* page, so that everything can be served up from cache without executing code in the action method and the view cshtml.

I am also aware of how basic page caching can be accomplished in ASP Core 2.1 using the built in functionality. All one needs to do is add a `[ResponseCaching(Duration=...)]` attribute to the action method, add the statements `services.AddResponseCaching()` and `app.UseResponseCaching()` to `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` respectively in Startup.cs. **Unfortunately, the page gets cached on the server instance, presumably in the server's memory.** I cannot figure out how to tell it to cache this page in Redis instead.

Basically I want something like `[ResponseCaching(Duration=..., CACHE=REDIS)]`. How does one accomplish this?

---

**Old ASP.NET 4 Equivalent**

In ASP.NET 4, one would simply add an `[OutputCache(Duration=...)]` attribute to the action, install the Microsoft.Web.RedisOutputCacheProvider NuGet package, and put the following in web.config

```
<caching>
    <outputCache defaultProvider="MyRedisOutputCache">
       <providers>
          <add name="MyRedisOutputCache" type=... host="" ssl="true" />
       </providers>
    </outputCache>
</caching>
```

And the entire page would subsequently be cached to Redis. It was really simple. This is exactly the functionality I am trying to replicate in ASP Core 2.1.

Comment: This is the default implementation https://github.com/aspnet/ResponseCaching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching/Internal/MemoryResponseCache.cs.  The important thing here is it implements `IResponseCache` so use this as a guide to implement a response cache using `IDistributedCache`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ASP.NET MVC Action Filters.

overwrite OnResultExecuted to store final result in Redis cache.

check if cache exist in OnActionExecuting.

the OnResultExecuted  call after the html view is ready, so you can store rendered html.

the OnActionExecuting call before the action so you can load data from cache.
check ASP.NET MVC Action Filters in this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/action-filters-in-mvc).